# How to supress known warnings when building Nginx on Linux?

Tags: nginx, gcc-warning

I am a linux amateur and am trying to build nginx on Debian (Lenny) for the first time.

Attemps to build nginx are failing and I receive the known warnings on sys_errorlist and sys_nerr as documented here: 
http://nginx.org/en/docs/sys_errlist.html

The documentation suggests this is a warning that I can ignore.  My question is what flag(s) do I need to include with **make** to tell it to ignore those warnings?

I have been pouring through the flag options with no real leads and searches only go as far as telling me that I can ignore the warnings.  It may be an obvious answer, perhaps why I can't find anything posted, so I'm asking those who are smarter than I.  Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They mean ignore as in you the human ignoring them, not as in telling the compiler to ignore them.  It shouldn't cause the compilation to fail unless you specify `-Werror`.

Comment: Yes, no problem installing and it runs just fine.  I need to understand gcc better.  Thanks.